# Solve ODE by integral transform

Tags: integral-transforms

$$g’’(x) + f^2*g’(x) + 4 g(x) = 0$$$$ g(0) = 0$$$$ g’(\pi/2) = 0$$ where $x \in\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is frequency.

If we use Laplace transform, the initial value of g'(pi/2) makes me cannot go further, but we don't have any ideas to do the Fourier transform. Can anyone give some comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Solution by Laplace transform**

Thanks to @Mikako's clarification, the symbol "$*$" means scalar multiplication instead of convolution. As such, let us deal with
\begin{align}
g''+f^2g+4g&=0&&x\in\mathbb{R},\\
g&=0&&x=0,\\
g'&=0&&x=\pi/2.
\end{align}

Apply Laplace transform to the governing ODE, we have
$$
\left[s^2G(s)-sg(0)-g'(0)\right]+f^2\left[sG(s)-g(0)\right]+4G(s)=0,
$$
where $G(s)=\mathcal{L}\{g\}(s)$. Note that $g(0)=0$, and the above equation reduces to
$$
\left(s^2+f^2s+4\right)G(s)=\alpha,
$$
where $\alpha=g'(0)$ will soon be determined by $g'(\pi/2)=0$. We have
$$
G(s)=\frac{\alpha}{s^2+f^2s+4}=\frac{\alpha}{\left(s+f^2/2\right)^2+\left(4-f^4/4\right)},
$$
or more specifically,
\begin{align}
G(s)&=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{4-f^4/4}}\frac{\sqrt{4-f^4/4}}{\left(s+f^2/2\right)^2+\left(4-f^4/4\right)},&&\text{if }\left|f\right|<2,\\
G(s)&=\alpha\frac{1}{\left(s+f^2/2\right)^2},&&\text{if }\left|f\right|=2,\\
G(s)&=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{f^4/4-4}}\frac{\sqrt{f^4/4-4}}{\left(s+f^2/2\right)^2-\left(f^4/4-4\right)},&&\text{if }\left|f\right|>2.
\end{align}
Perform the Laplace inverse transform for each case, and we obtain
\begin{align}
g(x)&=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{4-f^4/4}}e^{-\left(f^2/2\right)x}\sin\left(x\sqrt{4-f^4/4}\right),&&\text{if }\left|f\right|<2,\\
g(x)&=\alpha xe^{-\left(f^2/2\right)x},&&\text{if }\left|f\right|=2,\\
g(x)&=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{f^4/4-4}}e^{-\left(f^2/2\right)x}\sinh\left(x\sqrt{f^4/4-4}\right),&&\text{if }\left|f\right|>2.
\end{align}
Finally, apply $g'(\pi/2)=0$ to each case, and their respective $\alpha$ could be determined accordingly. For $\left|f\right|\ge 2$, it is a must that $\alpha=0$.

Note that if one wishes to get non-trivial $g$, the value of $f$ shall not be arbitrary. In fact, for those $\left|f\right|\le 2$, if $f$ satisfies
$$
\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{16-f^4}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{16-f^4}}{f^2},
$$
there would be no constraint on $\alpha$ (hence $g$ could be non-trivial).

**Original post: Mistaken "*" as convolution**

Suppose $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Apply Fourier transform to the equation with the convention
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\xi)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}{\rm d}x,\\
f(x)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}{\rm d}\xi,
\end{align}
and the equation becomes
$$
\widehat{g''}+\widehat{f^2*g'}+4\hat{g}=0.
$$
Provided that
$$
\widehat{g''}(\xi)=\left(2\pi i\xi\right)^2\hat{g}(\xi)=-4\pi^2\xi^2\hat{g}(\xi),
$$
and that (by [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem))
$$
\widehat{f^2*g'}(\xi)=\widehat{f^2}(\xi)\widehat{g'}(\xi)=\widehat{f^2}(\xi)\left[\left(2\pi i\xi\right)\hat{g}(\xi)\right]=2\pi i\xi\widehat{f^2}(\xi)\hat{g}(\xi),
$$
the governing equation becomes
$$
\left(-4\pi^2\xi^2+2\pi i\xi\widehat{f^2}(\xi)+4\right)\hat{g}(\xi)=0.
$$

Note that
$$
-4\pi^2\xi^2+2\pi i\xi\widehat{f^2}(\xi)+4=0\iff\widehat{f^2}(\xi)=\frac{4\pi^2\xi^2-4}{2\pi i\xi}\notin L^2(\mathbb{R}).
$$
Thus $-4\pi^2\xi^2+2\pi i\xi\widehat{f^2}(\xi)+4$ shall not be constantly zero, for which
$$
\hat{g}(\xi)=0.
$$
This result, as per the Fourier inverse transform, yields
$$
g(x)=0.
$$
Obviously, this $g$ satisfies both of the given conditions. Hence it is the only solution in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ we are able to figure out.

Comment: I don't think $f$ is a function of $x$, or OP would have indicated it. OP says it's a frequency, most likely a constant. In which case, the notation $*$ probably means multiplication rather than convolution

Comment: @Dylan: OMG... In that case, it becomes a most simply linear ODE, and why to use integral transform? -- So maybe this is an exercise for the integral transform method, just as OP mentioned the Laplace transform? Well, OP did not specify the domain of $g$. If it is defined on $\left[0,\infty\right)$, Fourier transform might not help then.

Comment: Yes, the notation * means multiplication, not convolution, and f is frequency. The problem we are facing is that we are not sure how to use Laplace transform in case g'(0) is not given. Because there is a pi/2, I guess something is related to frequency and use Fourier transform. By the way, thanks for answering and giving comments to my question.

Comment: @Mikako: Thank you for your clarification. I just updated my answer accordingly. Hope that would be helpful for you.

Comment: @hypernova: Thank you for your help. Your answer is really helpful for me!

Comment: @Mikako: My pleasure :-)